# odata model Cannot read property 'jsonHandler' of undefined sapui5

Tags: properties, undefined, typeerror

I am trying to access my odata service on an android device application on cordova getting the following error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonHandler' of undefined

For the following code:

var sServiceUrl =  "https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/ServiceName";

var sCredentials = oUsernameControl.getValue() + ':' + oPasswordControl.getValue();

var sCredentialsEncode = btoa(sCredentials);

var sAuthenticationToken = "Basic " + sCredentialsEncode ;

var mRequestHeader = {};

mRequestHeader["Authorization"] = sAuthenticationToken;

```
    //create object with ODATA model constructor parameters
    var oConstructorParams = {};
    oConstructorParams["json"] = true;
    oConstructorParams["headers"] = mRequestHeader;
    oConstructorParams["tokenhandling"] = true;

var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl,oConstructorParams);
```

And when I set the JSON Parameter to false I get the following error :
Cannot read property 'atomHandler' of undefined

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I can see your `tokenHandling` property is written not correct. Other than that, can't see any problem.

Comment: @keshet Thank you very much, the problem was that i was using local resources which did not have all libraries I needed to run the application